# Modules are not updating to the latest version

Tags: views, updating, security

I have some websites in the drupal. I need to update the security modules in the old version to the latest version. The list of security modules I tried to attempt is as below

1)colorbox (current - v2.15, updated version - v2.17)

2)colorbox_node (current - v3.5, updated version - v3.8)

3)link (current - not sure, updated v1.11)

4)wysiwyg (current - v2.6, updated v2.9)

currently using **drupal **v7.78****

For the site1 I have tried to update all the 4 modules. but it only updated the colorbox(v2.17), link(v2.9) and the colorbox_node(v3.5) and wysiwyg(v2.6) modules versions are not updated and remains at the same version

For site2 I have tried to update colorbox and colorbox_module but it only updated the colorbox_node(v3.8) and colorbox stayed at the same version(v2.15)

For the site3 I have tried to update all 4 modules and it updates only colorbox_module(v3.8) and link(v1.11). colorbox(v2.5) and wysiwyg(v2.6) modules stayed at the same version

I have replaced the new module files directly into the module folder in the server(/home/centos/public_html/site-x/sites/all/modules) ad then restarted the webserver(I found some other ways like updating via the admin interface, FTP but at the end, modules are only replaced in the server. So as an admin I directly replaced in the server)

Then tried the below steps to resolve the issue

- Applied 'flush all caches' in admin user
- Cleared all cached via 'configuration->developement->performance->clear all caches'
- Loaded with update.php (site/update.php) and updated from there(but here the modules are not showing as upgradable. only 'link' module is appeared and updated that module from update.php)
- Redeployed in the server many times
- Checked the module info file and verified that whether the replaced versions are correct

Note: Before attempting on the server, I tested locally, and all modules were properly updated, without any issues. But when updated in the live it is not updating. So in my perspective, I dont think it is a compatibility issue.

Any suggestions and troubleshooting are greatly appreciated; please guide me if I was incorrect in any of the above ways. If anyone needs more info please post in the comment. Honestly I dont know which tag to use for this question please feel free to edit if you want. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Run the server cron.

Comment: @Kevin Crons are executing automatically for every 3 hours. So it checks for updates for every 3 hours. I also executed the cron manually once but had no luck still the modules are in the same version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by following the below troubleshoots

- Before replacing the modules What I have done is, rename the module files like module-bkp in the same path(sites/all/modules/)
- So the site has taken the old file with the backup name(module-bkp)
- I have checked the 'system' table of the all the above sites which store the information about the modules
- There I found that all the modules are configured with the old file name(modules-bkp) which are renamed in the same path
- So I just moved the old module files to the other path. Then restarted the web server and cleared the cache in the admin panel

Now all the modules are updated to the latest version